# 2nd Law of Thermodynamics - Reformulation Regarding Spontaenity of Processes

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

It is said that 2nd law predicts direction of spontaneous process. It does so by saying that direction of spontaneous process is that in which entropy of the isolated system increases or stays the same, it can't decrease. What about non - spontaneous processes? They are externally driven by energy input. For them to happen entropy of the isolated system must increase or stay the same since no process can happen which would decrease entropy of the isolated system, this would violate 2nd law.  Thus 2nd law should predict the direction of non - spontaneous process as well as far as I understand. If so why is 2nd law almost always stated as to predict the direction of spontaneous procces? I think it is better to say that 2nd law predicts what processes are possible in nature regardless of their spontaenity. What are your thoughts? Is my reasoning correct and in harmony with 2nd law?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at, but a reversible process is non spontaneous and the total entropy change (system + surroundings) is zero, per the second law. A spontaneous process is irreversible to the total entropy change is greater than zero, again per second law.

Comment: Who says it only applies to spontaneous processes?

Comment: @Chet, I think it shouldn't, but it is mostly stated that way.

Comment: What I am saying is that for every process that happens regardless of its spontaenity entropy of the isolated system (universe is an isolated system) must increase.  This is not true only for spontaneous process, but for non - spontaneous as well. There can be no process which would decrease entropy of isolated system. So, why is 2nd law usually formulated that it predicts direction of spontaneous process when it can also predict the direction of non - spontaneous process?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up *spontaneous process* vs *unspontaneous process* with *isolated system* vs *non-isolated system*.

- If you state the 2nd law of thermodynamics **for isolated systems** then you are right in stating that the entropy will not decrease **for any processes**, spontaneous or not.
- If you state the law **for non-isolated systems** then you can *only* state that entropy will not decrease **for spontaneous processes**.

Because, as you rightly say, an unspontaneous process such as my action of willfully ordering a system will decrease it's entropy. But that is only because we then aren't including the body and the processes that produce the forces that let me create this local entropy decrease. If you included that - the whole picture, the isolated system - the 2nd law of thermodynamics does state that the entropy won't as a whole decrease.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Whether or not process is spontaneous, entropy change of the isolated system (universe) must increase. So, there is the same condition for both types of processes. Why is than 2nd law most often stated that it predicts the direction of only spontaneous processes when it can also predict the direction of non - spontaneous processes? 2nd law predicts what processes are actually possible in nature regardless of their spontaenity if we look at the isolated system (universe) as a whole (system of interest and surrondings).

Comment: I actually don't understand why does entropy of closed system need to increase for spontaneous process? Aren't free energies predictors of what processes are possible for closed systems (Helmholtz and Gibbs) depending on how process are carried? Gibbs energy of closed syetem should decrease for any process in nature carried at constant pressure. This is equivalent with that entropy of both system and surrondings should always increase.

Comment: @DarioMirić "*Why is than 2nd law most often stated that it predicts the direction of only spontaneous processes*" Because that is the most generalised version of the law. As I explained, this is how you must state the law if you are talking generally about all possible systems. It *cannot* predict the direction of non-spontaneous processes unless you also know that it is an isolated system.

Comment: @DarioMirić "*2nd law predicts what processes are actually possible in nature regardless of their spontaenity i*" Hmm, I would argue that processes in nature in general are spontaneous. I'd presume that your definition of "spontaneous" comes with human interaction, with conscious choices. Otherwise we might not be talking about the same thing.

Comment: @DarioMirić "*I actually don't understand why does entropy of closed system need to increase for spontaneous process?*" Actually, this law is not entirely certain, to be honest. It is a statistically based law. It is actually not impossible to obserbe entropy reductions even for isolated systems, if the systems is simple. But with more complexity, the tendency towards entropy increase for any process happening grows rapidly...

Comment: ... Just think of throwing two dice - the most likely outcome is a sum of 7. That is the macrostate with most possible microstates. In other words, that is the most likely outcome, which is another way of saying that this is a state of highest disorder, highest entropy. But a sum of 2 is also possible - we won't expect it, it is less likely that other outcomes, but it is possible. But now throw 100 dice. Would you expect the sum to be 200? That would require every single die to show a 1. This is not impossible - but the probability is very tiny. The propability of results that correspond...

Comment: ...to increased entropy grows rapidly with the number of microstates. With billions of billions of particles, energy states etc. in a system, we thus as a general whole expect the outcome to be the one that is most probable, the one associated with highest value of entropy. *That* is what the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics states. The statistical tendency, but not a requirement. It is thus not theoretically impossible to see a process in an isolated system decreasing in entropy - but it might still be so unlikely that we call it *practically* impossible. And trust that it will never happen.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said about probabilistic nature of the law. When I say spontaneous I mean process which happens without external aid of energy (heat transfer from hot to cold object, zinc oxidation and copper reduction in Daniel's Cell) and non - spontaneous process requires energy input to happen (zinc reduction and copper oxidation in Daniell's cell - electrolysis). Can you tell me why does entropy of non - isolated system need to increase in spontaneous process? Can you point to a reference for that?

Comment: You said: "It cannot predict the direction of non-spontaneous processes unless you also know that it is an isolated system." Both system surroundings together are the universe which is isolated system. How would we predict the direction of spontaneous process than? The fact that heat goes from hot to cold object. We can also make it go other way around with energy input - non spontaneous process. Cylic process in refrigerators.

Comment: @DarioMirić "*Can you tell me why does entropy of non - isolated system need to increase in spontaneous process?*" It doesn't... Possibly you mix the words? The entropy of a **non**-isolated system can increase or decrease depending on the external parameters that influence this system from the outside.

Comment: @DarioMirić "*We can also make it go other way around with energy input - non spontaneous process.*" Yes, agreed. We can do that with energy input as you state. But it requires processes within our bodies to supply this energy input. The 2nd law of thermodynamics claims - as a law of nature - that while some processes can increase entropy and others can decrease entropy within the same system, the *overall* entropy will increase. Meaning, the entropy increases will be bigger than the entropy decreases.

Comment: This is a quote from your first answer: "If you state the law for non-isolated systems then you can only state that entropy will not decrease for spontaneous processes." So, that we are clear about mixing words. But, I agree with what you said in your last answer. My question still remains why is 2nd law stated only for spontaneous process and not for non - spontaneous since we agree that in both processes entropy of universe should increase? This predicts their direction regardless of spontaenity. Spontaenity is just concerned about energy input.